# Prove or give counter example: for every real number $y$ there exists a real number $x$ such that $e^{3x} + y = y^2 +1$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I started like this and am not sure if I'm on the right path.

Let $y$ be an arbitrary real number. Let $x=0.$
So we get
$$\begin{aligned} e^{3\cdot 0}=&\; y^2-y+1\\
               1 =&\; y^2-y+1\\
               0 =&\; y^2-y\\
               0 =&\; y(y-1)
\end{aligned}$$

and now I'm stuck, I tried contradiction, and it didn't work. So I just don't know where to go from here. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Let's see: Is it possible thar $y^2-y+1\le 0$? Since that polynomial has positive leading coefficient, to be negative it has to cross the X-axis, this is, have real roots; but $\sqrt{(-1)^2-4·1·1}=\sqrt{-3}\notin \Bbb R$, so the polynomial is always positive.

Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{3x}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{3x}=+\infty$, $e^{3x}$ has to take any positive value in between, since it is a continuous function (Rolle's theorem).

Then for every $y\in\Bbb R$ we have $y^2-y+1>0$, so there has to be some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $e^{3x}$ takes that value.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

We have $e^{3x}> 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ so if we can find a $y$ such that $y^2-y+1\leq0$ we get a contradiction.

But $y^2-y+1=(y-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}>0$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$. Thus the statement is true. In other words for any $y\in\mathbb R$ take $x=\frac{1}{3}\ln(y^2-y+1)$ which is a real number, then $e^{3x} + y = y^2 +1$ are required.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2-y+1-e^{3x}=0$$
the equation is quadratic in y, use the quadratic equation:
$$y=\frac{1+\sqrt{e^{3x}-3}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{e^{3x}-3}}{2}$$
since the range of $e^{3x}-3$ spans the positive real numbers, the combined range of the two equations spans the real numbers.